# Additional line in Modern CV

Tags: moderncv

I try to create my CV with Modern CV. Here is a small code :

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}                
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage[inner=1.2cm,outer=1.2cm,top=0.4cm,bottom=0.4cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{sourcesanspro}
\renewcommand*{\sectionfont}{\Large\bfseries\scshape}

\firstname{\Large{Aaaa}}
\familyname{\Large{\textsc{Bbbb}}}
\title{\normalsize Iiiiiiiiiiiii }
\address{\textbf{113 iiiii}}{\textbf{000 Vvvvv}}  
\mobile{\textbf{0000000}}             
\email{aaaaaa@aaa.fr} 
\extrainfo{\textbf{bla bla}}  

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\maketitle

\section{Experience}
\end{document}
```

As you can see "Experience" section is preceded by a huge blue line. I would like the same line to appear *after*  "Experience" and to expand as long as I want (until it reaches the margin as a limitation). Is that possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following lines in your preamble

```
\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{sm}{%
  \par\addvspace{2.5ex}%
  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}%
  \parbox[t]{\hintscolumnwidth}{\strut\raggedleft\raisebox{\baseletterheight}{\color{color1}\rule{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.95ex}}}%
  \hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
  \parbox[t]{\maincolumnwidth}{\strut\sectionstyle{#2}\hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
    \strut\raisebox{\baseletterheight}{\color{color1}\rule{\maincolumnwidth-\widthof{\sectionstyle{#2}}-\separatorcolumnwidth}{0.95ex}}}%
  \par\nobreak\addvspace{1ex}\@afterheading}% to avoid a pagebreak after the heading
\makeatother
```

to achieve what you want.

MWE (notice that I've added the option `sans` to `moderncv` since you're loading `sourcesanspro`):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage[inner=1.2cm,outer=1.2cm,top=0.4cm,bottom=0.4cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{sourcesanspro}
\renewcommand*{\sectionfont}{\Large\bfseries\scshape}

\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{sm}{%
  \par\addvspace{2.5ex}%
  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}%
  \parbox[t]{\hintscolumnwidth}{\strut\raggedleft\raisebox{\baseletterheight}{\color{color1}\rule{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.95ex}}}%
  \hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
  \parbox[t]{\maincolumnwidth}{\strut\sectionstyle{#2}\hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
    \strut\raisebox{\baseletterheight}{\color{color1}\rule{\maincolumnwidth-\widthof{\sectionstyle{#2}}-\separatorcolumnwidth}{0.95ex}}}%
  \par\nobreak\addvspace{1ex}\@afterheading}% to avoid a pagebreak after the heading
\makeatother

\firstname{\Large{Aaaa}}
\familyname{\Large{\textsc{Bbbb}}}
\title{\normalsize Iiiiiiiiiiiii }
\address{\textbf{113 iiiii}}{\textbf{000 Vvvvv}}
\mobile{\textbf{0000000}}
\email{aaaaaa@aaa.fr}
\extrainfo{\textbf{bla bla}}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\maketitle

\section{Experience}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]